# Validate Captcha using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, captcha, antd

I'm working on a simple form that generate random code, then check if the user input the correct code.

My problem is I don't know how to match the user input and the generated code(from different component).

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

Please check my code

[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/4rr7qm6mx7)

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormItem
          validateStatus={captchaError ? "error" : ""}
          help={captchaError || ""}
        >
          {getFieldDecorator("captcha", {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input code!" }]
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="key" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
              type="text"
              placeholder="captcha"
              addonAfter={<Captcha />}
            />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            disabled={hasErrors(getFieldsError())}
          >
            Log in
          </Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch child value in the Parent. You can use Refs to Components approach, as suggested here: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909

Here is the [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wnm16r06x), which will display an alert on inputting right captcha.

This will help! :)

Answer (score 0):

`antd` has `getFieldsValue`  go for [documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/).
Another way to get text via `onchange` event like

```
handleValueChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("textValue", e.target.value)
}
```

And your `input` as

```
<Input
   prefix={<Icon type="key" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
   type="text"
   onChange={this.handleValueChange.bind(this)}
   placeholder="captcha"
   addonAfter={<Captcha />}
 />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put the function that generates the random number outside the captcha component and pass the random numbers as props, something like:

```
 <Captcha numbers={xxxx} />
```

Comment: I really want to know how to do it